# How to change the conditions of a macro under circumstances?

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, macros

Well, what I want to do is edit if a particular cell has a particular value.

For example, if cell A18 has any number higher than 6, it will make the value of cell O2 say `=A18*0.5`, however, if it says 6, O2 will say `=A18*0.6`.

Do you understand what I am talking about? 
If you are, can you please find a good macro to do this?

Thanks, all hope appreciated. :)

Comment: Google something like "excel write formula into cell from macro". My first hit gave the answer

Comment: What do you mean by first hit exactly?

Comment: First Google search result. And I said 'my' because Google tailors search results for individual users, so your results may differ. Anyway, that URL was http://www.ozgrid.com/forum/showthread.php?t=61884

Comment: Yes, that was mine as well. However, I want an if in the macro code, not in the function, but I'm gonna try doing that.